# Vaadin LoginForm component showing empty

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I have some code to add the Vaadin LoginForm component to my page

```java
LoginForm component = new LoginForm();
component.addLoginListener(e -> {
       boolean isAuthenticated = myAuthMethod();
       if (isAuthenticated) {
            System.out.println("TEST");
        } else {
            component.setError(true);
        }
    });

 add(component);
```

But it just shows a blank page.  My dom editor in Chrome shows an empty tag...

I am running Vaadin 14.07

[image]

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: It works fine locally for me... Do you have any errors in console? And could you post a complete view? Or how are you adding it to a view?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. It might be another reason. However, I could solve it by running a clean and an install of Maven.

Comment: While clean might sometimes be the only way out with crappy build-tools, I am not a big fan of cargo culting "have you tried turning it off and on again".  Had you tried, if just one of the build/prepare frontend tasks of the vaadin14 maven plugin fixed it on it's own?

Answer (score 0):

When adding a component for the first time, the internal frontend dependencies list may not yet have that component registered and therefore do not load the related client side files from npm on start up time.

In that case a simple maven install is needed to update the frontend dependencies list. After that starting the server should automatically load the respective files and thus show the component correctly.

Comment: If that does not solve it, then it may also be [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59035219/3441504) ([related github issue](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/6850)). Only happens when no `@Route` component directly uses/imports the component in question.

Answer (score 0):

The `LoginForm` is working for me. Your problem may be outside the code you showed here. We would need to know how you instantiated and displayed the `LoginForm`.

## Example app

Here is an example app using Vaadin 14.1.2. I used a new "Plain Java Servlet" flavor project generated by the [Vaadin starter page](https://vaadin.com/start/latest). I left the POM file untouched. I ran the app using the bundled Jetty server, and used Google Chrome Version 79.0.3945.79 (Official Build) (64-bit) for macOS.

I created a simple `User` class.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.UUID;

public class User
{
    private UUID id;
    private String username;

    public User ( UUID id , String username )
    {
        this.id = Objects.requireNonNull( id );
        this.username = Objects.requireNonNull( username );
    }

    // ------------|  Object  |---------------------------------
    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object o )
    {
        if ( this == o ) return true;
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) return false;
        User user = ( User ) o;
        return id.equals( user.id );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( id );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "User{ " +
                "id=" + id +
                " | username='" + username + '\'' +
                " }";
    }
}
```

And an `Authenticator` class. Comment-out or in the lines for always passing the user or always denying the user, for this simple demo case.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public class Authenticator
{
    Optional < User > authenticate ( String username , String password )
    {
        User user = new User( UUID.fromString( "76317e14-20a5-11ea-978f-2e728ce88125" ) , username );
        return Optional.of( user );
        //        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

An dummy content view to show after the user has successfully authenticated.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;

public class ContentView extends VerticalLayout
{
    public ContentView ( )
    {
        this.add( new H1( "Content goes here" ) );
    }
}
```

Pull it all together with this `MainView` layout.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.AbstractLogin;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginForm;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinSession;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
@PWA ( name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    public MainView ( )
    {
        this.display();
    }

    private void display ( )
    {
        if ( Objects.isNull( VaadinSession.getCurrent().getAttribute( User.class ) ) )
        {
            this.removeAll();
            this.add( this.makeLoginForm() );
        } else
        { // Else we have a User, so must be authenticated.
            this.removeAll();
            this.add( new ContentView() );
        }
    }

    private LoginForm makeLoginForm ( )
    {
        Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();
        LoginForm component = new LoginForm();
        component.addLoginListener( ( AbstractLogin.LoginEvent loginEvent ) -> {
            Optional < User > user = authenticator.authenticate( loginEvent.getUsername() , loginEvent.getPassword() );
            if ( user.isPresent() )
            {
                VaadinSession.getCurrent().setAttribute( User.class , user.get() );
                this.display();
            } else
            {
                component.setError( true );
            }
        } );
        return component;
    }
}
```

For a "sign-out" feature, your code needs only to remove the `User` object from the session, and call `MainView::display` again.